# suggest a better way to handle exception in case

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I am doing an assignment for class where we turn military time into standard time and thought I would be clever to have separate functions for getting input and checking the input -- my reasoning being that if the check_input function failed I could keep looping through the get_inputs function until the user entered it in the correct format.

However, when I enter jibberish like "jklfd" my get_input function crashes because it can't turn it into a list which is part of the function.

Is there a better way to handle exceptions in this case? Also any general tips or advice is always appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
    __author__ = 'Ethan'
#This program takes input in military time in the format hour:minutes and outputs
#the time in standard time hour:minute AM/PM

def main():
    print_intro()
    while True:
        mil_h, m = get_inputs()
        if check_input(mil_h,m):
            break
    reformat_time(mil_h,m)

def print_intro():
    print("This program takes input as military time from user")
    print("in format hour:minute ex. 23:34")
    print("and outputs the time in standard AM/PM format")
    print("ex. from above 11:34 PM")

def get_inputs():
    raw = input("Enter time: ")
    time_list = raw.split(":")
    mil_h = int(time_list[0])
    m = int(time_list[1])
    return mil_h, m

def check_input(mil_h,m):
    try:
        if mil_h >= 24 or mil_h <0:
            print("Time must be in format hh:mm")
            print("Hour must be in range 0 to 23")
            return False
        elif m >= 60 or m <0:
            print("Time must be in format hh:mm")
            print("Minute must be in range 0 to 59")
            return False
        else:
            return True
    except:
        print("Input must be in military time in format hh:mm")

def reformat_time(mil_h,m):
    am_pm = "AM"
    if mil_h == 12:
        am_pm = "PM"
        stand_h = 12
    elif mil_h > 12:
        am_pm = "PM"
        stand_h = mil_h % 12
    else:
        stand_h = mil_h
    print(stand_h,':', m,' ', am_pm, sep='')

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Before splitting the string use an if statement,

```
if(raw.contains(":")&& raw.length()>=3 && raw) {
list=raw.split(":")
//rest of code
} else { throw exception}
```

The code for the exception should be edited to look like this:

```
except:
println("Code must be in military format")
get_inputs()
//recall the check_input method for the values found in get_inputs
check_input()
```

This way you know that raw is in the right format, you may want to add more prerequisites for raw (like making sure it only contains numbers), so that the program won't crash with unwanted input.   (Sorry for the syntax, I don't know python explicitly)

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I go that route though, how would I go back and ask the user for input again if their input failed the tests?

Comment: Use a while loop, and a boolean variable to track success